# Three.js - ExtrudeGeometry with the top face tilted such that the plane of the face has a certain normal

Tags: three.js

I need a shape similar to a polygonal prism standing on one its (non-rectangular) polygon faces but where the top face could be tilted.

[image: Similar to this image, but it need not be a square/rectangle but any polygon (concave/convex)]

Similar to this image, but it need not be a square/rectangle but any polygon (concave/convex).

I considered the following ways of doing it, but they feel sub-optimal:

- Extruding a ShapeGeometry and using changing the points (BufferGeometry attributes) of the top face (by checking for a specific normal in BufferGeometry attributes) to translate to points existing on the desired plane.
- Make the bottom Shape using ShapeGeometry. Copy the geometry and translate and rotate it. Make the sides Geometries using the vertices used to define the polygon. (and somehow merge all these geometries)

I also need to be able to have different tilts for both the top and bottom faces later.

Comment: Why does option 1 feel sub-optimal? That's how I would do it, except I don't know what you mean by checking for normals. Just project the vertices you want onto your plane, and then recompute the normals if necessary.

Comment: @Berthur , By checking for normals, I meant differentiating the points in the bufferGeometry corresponding to the top face by checking its corresponding normal. Is there a way I can filter the vertices I want (triangulated points of the top face in BufferGeometry) after making an ExtrudeGeometry? It was easier in previous versions of three.js supporting Geometry (not BufferGeometry) to filter out the top points.

Comment: Oh, well the vertices will be created in pre-defined order so you can just get them by index. If your base has *n* points then you need *n+1, ..., 2n* or equivalent depending on the geometry format.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. (atlest in r146 of three.js)
I didn't find the positions to be group-able by setting some index and didn't see any pattern to group them in an obvious way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a wrapper around the bufferGeometry class where you take in the top and bottom vertices of the polygon.
Triangulate the sides of the polygon and create your custom Float32Array.
Use this for the position attribute of bufferGeometry, I guess you could use the same array for UVs as well (I'm not sure).

You could refer these for triangulation

> https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/ShapeUtils

> https://github.com/mapbox/delaunator